# Custom Asp.net server controls that will work in MVC and Web Forms?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

Is it possible to develop controls that will work in both Asp.net Web Forms and MVC?

It seems that we're heading for a situation where we now have to maintain another set of code for MVC over and above the code being maintained for Silverlight and Web Forms and heaven knows what else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but not pretty. MVC does not have the `ViewState`.